# Result from $X^2+Y^2=p^{n-1}$ with $p^{n-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{8}$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm reading an article and they have the equation $X^2+Y^2=p^{n-1}$ where $p$ is a prime and $p^{n-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{8}$ and $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$.

They conclude that since $p^{n-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{8}$ it must follow that 
$$\begin{cases}
 X \equiv 0 \pmod{4} \\ Y \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{4}
 \end{cases}
 \textrm{ or }
\begin{cases}
 X \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{4} \\ Y \equiv 0 \pmod{4}
 \end{cases}.$$

Where does this come from?

Comment: not much to it. One of $x,y$ is odd, therefore its square is $1 \pmod 8$  Then the square of the other one is $0 \pmod 8,$ meaning the variable itself is divisible by $4.$ Compare: $2^2 = 4 \equiv 4 \pmod 8$

Comment: @WillJagy I was just writing an answer similar to what you commented above, but I discarded it to avoid basically repeating what you just wrote. Even though there's "not much to it", you should consider making it into an answer yourself.

Comment: @JohnOmielan you go ahead. I don't have the energy to put in more detail than that.

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks. I wanted to be considerate if you wanted to post what you wrote as an answer yourself. As you can see, I perhaps gave more detail than necessary in my answer, but I usually prefer to be comprehensive with what I write here as I would like them to be quite easily readable and accessible not only to the OP, but also most other people who may read it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note $p^{n-1} \equiv 1 \pmod 8$ means both sides of $X^2 + Y^2 = p^{n-1}$ is odd. Thus, one of $X$ and one of $Y$ must be even and the other odd. Consider $X$ to be even and $Y$ to be odd. As $Y$ is odd (so $Y \equiv \pm 1 \pmod 4$), when squared, it's $Y^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 8$. With $X$ being even, if it's $X \equiv 2 \pmod 8$, then it's square is $X^2 \equiv 4 \pmod 8$, so $X^2 + Y^2 \equiv 5 \pmod 8$. However, since $X^2 + Y^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 8$, this means $X \equiv 0 \pmod 4$.

The two sets of congruences you ask about just list this for $X$ and $Y$ as I describe above, and since the equation is symmetric in $X$ and $Y$, it also lists the  possibilities for the conditions on $X$ and $Y$ to be switched around.